# Android Intent, Action Create Document, Opens the file explorer multiple times creating duplicate 0b files

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I am developing an app for filling pdf forms, I am saving the pdf to the internal storage and then sharing it using the intent ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT. This intent returns a URI which i then copy my local pdf into.

All this works fine however the intent opens a file explorer popup so that the user can choose where to save the pdf, and here in lies the problem, when the user presses SAVE; the app creates a 0b file in that location (as it should), but then it reopens the file explorer prompting the user to SAVE again, this happens two or three times and then it finally close for real at which point the pdf data overwrites the latest of the now numerous 0b files.

```java
public int WRITE_REQUEST_CODE=45;
   ...
           @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void buttonExport(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exporting - This will take around 1min", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Template of PDF with acrofields (template.pdf).
        // TRY to open the pdf stored in the raw res directory
        // then convert it to a file object by copying it
        try {
            //

                InputStream inputStream =null;

            if (template.equals("crfminortemplate")){
                 inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.crfminorpdftemplat);
            }
            else   if (template.equals("crfmajortemplate")){
                 inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.crfmajorpdftemplat);
            }
            File tempFile = new File(getFilesDir(),template);
            //
            copyFile(inputStream, new FileOutputStream(tempFile));

            // Now Questions res is tempFile ..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't create temp file ", e);
        }


        try {
            PDFManipulation.fillPDF(view, template, fileName, Answers);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "Export Complete - save to drive or email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       sharePDF(getFilesDir()+"/"+fileName+".pdf");


    }

    private void sharePDF(String PDFPPath) {
        Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.cst_app_v3", new File(getFilesDir(),fileName+".pdf"));
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();

        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sent from CST App Android " + PDFPPath);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        startActivityForResult(shareIntent,0);
        Intent saveIntent = new Intent();
        saveIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        saveIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,fileName+".pdf");
        saveIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        saveIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        saveIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        saveIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        startActivityForResult(saveIntent,WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share or Save ...");
        Intent[]arrayofintent = {saveIntent};
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,arrayofintent);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent,0);
        startActivity(chooserIntent);

        Log.d("Alert",path.getAuthority()+" "+ path.getPath());
    }


 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == WRITE_REQUEST_CODE) {
       //DO THE COPY PASTE FROM LOCAL to THE URI data
       }
}
```

Again

I want the user to start the save intent and have the file selector popup once let the user name the file and choose the save location, press save and then return to my the my app where the pdf is copied to the location they specified

if anyone knows/has experienced this issue or thinks they know what might be happening it would be great to hear from you.

Comment: Can you show the whole method where you `startActivityForResult(saveIntent,WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);` I use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` fine without any problems like this. As you might be firing multiple intents. Can you also give details about the API level you are testing this on.

Comment: ill update the post with that info give me a sec to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `startActivityForResult` or `startActivity` it will start a new Activity.

So I count 4 of these in your example code but with only 2 calls that will actually return a result that would cause a file to be written.

To fix this just remove all the `startActivityForResult` or `startActivity` EXCEPT for the third one which you change to `startActivityForResult(chooserIntent,WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);`

This works (was tested) BUT provides a very bad UI experience as you have to know to select the `Files` App to save the document.

It would be much better to split these to different types of action in to separate menu items, Buttons, Floating Action Buttons, or however you getting the user to "Share or Save" as you can provide a better UI than the Intent chooser.

Comment: This Solution worked ... i also had to add a 1sec timer before overwriting the 0b file with the pdf data as without the gap the application would hang with the file explorer open creating confusion now its run on a different thread to the ui and waits till the ui is loaded anyway ... thanks for your help i did not know StartActivityForResult ran the intent